# Problem in iterating through ProcKind values

Tags: vba, excel

I am a novice in VBA but recently following @Marcucciboy2, @Cindy Meister and @Mathieu Guindon for their excellent contribution in VBA. In the topic **Export VBA Procedures (Sub/Function) Separately** I tried a little in guidelines of @Mathieu Guindon and come across a few new problems.

```
'Public Const vbext_pk_Get As Long = 3
'Public Const vbext_pk_Let As Long = 1
'Public Const vbext_pk_Set As Long = 2
'Public Const vbext_pk_Proc As Long = 0

'sub function
'sub function

Sub test3()
Rw = 15
Dim Vbc As VBComponent
Dim Lno, StLine, LineCnt, CmntPos, ParenthPos As Long
Dim Line, Pname1, Pname2, SubOrFun As String, Pk As vbext_ProcKind

Pk = vbext_pk_Proc

    For Each Vbc In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        Lno = 1
        Pname1 = ""
            For Lno = 1 To Vbc.CodeModule.CountOfLines
            Line = Vbc.CodeModule.Lines(Lno, 1)
            'For Pk = 0 To 3                   **'Activating this For loop cuasing Excel to come to a halt (not responding)'**
            Pname2 = Vbc.CodeModule.ProcOfLine(Lno, Pk)

            'Filter the line only up to the 1st comment character or 1st parenthesis
            '(due to possibility of some parameter name may ends with "sub " or "function ")
            CmntPos = InStr(1, Line, "'")
            ParenthPos = InStr(1, Line, "(")
            If CmntPos > 0 Then Line = Trim(Left(Line, CmntPos - 1))
            If ParenthPos > 0 Then Line = Left(Line, ParenthPos - 1)


                If Line <> "" And Pname1 <> Pname2 Then
                Line = LCase(Replace(Line, Pname2, ""))   'In some cases function name can also contain "sub" like "Batch_subtraction" and vice verse some of the procedures name can be  "functionality_View"
                SubOrFun = IIf(InStr(1, Line, "function") > 0, "Function", "Sub")

                StLine = 0
                LineCnt = 0
                StLine = Vbc.CodeModule.ProcStartLine(Pname2, Pk)     'Startline including comment lines
                LineCnt = Vbc.CodeModule.ProcCountLines(Pname2, Pk)   'line Count including comment lines
                Pname1 = Pname2
' sub function

                Rw = Rw + 1
                ' following lines are only for trial/debugging purpose, the results being stored in excel cells
                ' in actual case here should be  the lines of the procedure can be processed by StLine and LineCnt
                ' Or added to a collection for further processing
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(Rw, 1).Value = Vbc.Name
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(Rw, 2).Value = Pname2
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(Rw, 3).Value = SubOrFun
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(Rw, 4).Value = StLine
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(Rw, 5).Value = LineCnt
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(Rw, 6).Value = Lno
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(Rw, 7).Value = Line
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(Rw, 8).Value = Pk
                End If
            'Next
            Next
    Next

End Sub
'sub function
```

It is working fine. 
Now, When I am trying iterate through Pk= 0 to 3 excel is coming to a halt (failing to respond). Also whatever is the value of Pk finally in Excel it is showing as 0. What may be the catch? This is purely due to academic purpose.
[image: sample result]

Comment: what reference needs to be added for vbext_ProcKind defs?

Comment: @Jeeped that's the VBE Extensibility API (`VBIDE`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pname2 = Vbc.CodeModule.ProcOfLine(Lno, Pk)
```

Usage of `ProcOfLine` is awkward, because the `ProcKind` parameter isn't just passed `ByRef` because `ByRef` is the default in VBA: the `ProcKind` parameter is passed `ByRef` because the `ProcKind` enum value is an **output** of the function!

```
Dim Pk As vbext_ProcKind
Pname2 = Vbc.CodeModule.ProcOfLine(Lno, Pk)
Debug.Print Pk ' <~ that's the ProcKind of procedure Pname2 which Lno belongs to
```

The signature looks like this:

> ```
> Property Get ProcOfLine(Line As Long, ProcKind As vbext_ProcKind) As String
> ```

Its usage might have been clearer if it were like this:

> ```
> Property Get ProcOfLine(ByVal Line As Long, ByRef outProcKind As vbext_ProcKind) As String
> ```